# excelApp.CreateDispatch() returns a zero value : failure

Tags: c++

I have the following piece of code in Visual C++ 2005 : :

```cpp
class _Application:public COleDispatchDriver {....};

_Application excelApp;

excelApp.CreateDispatch((LPCTSTR)_T("Excel.Application")))
```

But the call to `excelApp.CreateDispatch((LPCTSTR)_T("Excel.Application")))`  returns a zero value indicating a failure .

Could you please tell me what could be the possible reason ?

PS : I copied the above piece of code from an another solution ( Visual C++ 2005) where this works perfectly fine on the same machine .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer people :

I just had to call CoInitialize(0)   before the above piece of code .

and then CoUninitialize() after all are done  .

Cool it was ....